# How to make the child class inherit SOME of the methods and properties from its parent?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

We all do know if use `super().__init__()` we import all the properties from the parent object.

But what if I want to inherit only **some** of the properties - *not all of them* ?

The benefit it would be if I develop an app for the end user to see and access only the right values and methods.

This is what I end up with...

```py
    class Window:
      def __init__(self, width, height, minimize, maximize, close):
          self.width = width
          self.height = height
          self.min = minimize
          self.max = maximize
          self.close = close

     @property # or regular method
     def resolution(self):
         return [self.width, self.height]

    class Button(Window):
      def __init__(self, width, height, btn):
          super().__init__(width, height, None, None, None)
          self.width = int(self.width / 3) * btn # some calculus here
          self.height = int(self.height / 3) * btn 

      @property
      def resolution(self):
          pass

    button_1 = Button(102, 345, 1)
    button_2 = Button(674, 54, 2)
```

If I run `dir(button_1)`, I see all the methods and properties ... like so:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'close', 'height', 'max', 'min', 'resolution', 'width']
```

I can override methods / special properties with `pass`, and initialize properties with `None`, but I still have them in the instance.

How to get rid of them for good ?

Comment: There are some ways of approximating what you want, but it seems fundamentally contradictory to the actual purpose of inheritance. When you create a `Cat` subclass of `Man`, you're saying that every cat is also a man.  Why do you feel you need to do this?

Comment: I put a better example. Hope this help. If not maybe I don't understant the importance of inheritance.